Extend a value with ones in SystemVerilog
When assigning a narrow bit vector to a wider one in SystemVerilog like this:
logic [3:0] narrow;
logic [7:0] wide;
assign wide = narrow;

it will zero-extend narrow. Is there a nice way to one-extend it instead?  I do not mean sign-extend, and I don't want to explicitly have to put the size in. I'm thinking something like this:
assign wide = { '1, narrow };

But it doesn't work because you aren't allowed unsized values in a concatenation. Is there a nice solution to this?

Ok I found a convenient way:
assign wide = ~{~narrow};

If you just do this:
assign wide = ~narrow;

then rather counter-intuitively SV will zero extend narrow to the width of wide before inverting it. My god do we need a sane SV replacement. Anyway in this case we can use that fact. The {...} concatenation protects the ~narrow inside it from being similarly extended. So this is equivalent to (in a saner language):
wide = ~(zero_extend(~(narrow)));

which is of course equivalent to one-extending it. It does add back-to-back inverters but if your optimiser can't eliminate those then you have bigger problems.
Also the "WTF SV?" level is quite high on this so if you do use it, definitely add a comment explaining it!

nice trick, but I would not recommend using it. The intention of the code will not be understood by most of the verilog programmers without comments. Or you should probably create a function 'one_extend(narrow)' in such a case.

Yeah I did note that at the end. I'm not sure you can do this with a function and have it infer all the widths properly. Feel free to prove me wrong though!

I think dave_59 suggestion with 'let' could be a good approach.

The easiest thing to do is
wide = ~{~narrow};

Verilog extends or truncates operands to their width in context before applying any operators. The width of operands of in a concatenation are self-determined, so the first negation is done on 4-bits, the second on 8 bits.  These are points most people don't realize until they make their first mistake.
You can put this into a reusable let definition:
let one_extend(op) = ~{~op};

then you can write
wide = one_extend(narrow);

You can also take advantage of the fact that Verilog truncates wider operands to narrower in an assignment.
wide = { 123'('1),narrow }; // some large width
wide = { $bits(wide)'('1),narrow }; // maximum possible width
wide = { ($bits(wide)-$bits(narrow))'('1),narrow }; // exact width


You can use $bits to calculate the size and use the replicated concatenation operator:
assign wide = { {($bits(wide) - $bits(narrow)){1'b1}}, narrow };

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023 section 20.6.2 Expression size system function.
If you had used parameters in the signal declarations, then you could have done the calculation using the parameters instead of $bits.
